# Facebook insights for Posts by Others

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-insights

Is there any way to get insights for posts by others (assuming that I'm page admin). Or at least any evaluations of "posts by others" organic reach? Presumably it will be extremely small, but I need a little bit more accurate estimations.

Comment: Seems Facebook Insights does not include the "Posts by Others".

Comment: Yep. But maybe somebody knows related magic links with research papers or fb-data team leaks.

Comment: Hope the *somebody* will read this question.